# Is it possible to mark price on the scale?

Tags: pine-script

Just like manually drawing a horizontal line marks price on the scale. Trying to mimic the same with `hline` but no luck.

```
hline(100, title="test-line", color=color.white)
```

Is it even possible at all?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hline()` does not display values in the scale. `plot()` will.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out in the morning and let you know.

Comment: Nope, Doesn't seem to work :( Can please give an example?

Comment: Maybe take a look here @baburao     https://kodify.net/tradingview/indicator-settings/scale-indicator/ I think you can find a way to apply it to plot().

Comment: @EdoardoRosso I had `Indicator Last Value Label` unchecked in chart settings. `plot()` indeed worked after checking that. So, I'm accepting this answer. - Thanks for the link tho :)

Answer (score 1):

Change color, background hides the line.
Try put `linestyle=hline.style_dashed` just for testing purpose in function.

Comment: Um. that's not what I'm asking tho. See [image](https://i.ibb.co/tQkGF7V/Capture.png). Red and yellow line doesn't mark/ label the price, unlike current price.
Thanks for taking interest btw, much appreciated :)